# XNA spritebatch and primative using different axis with same effect

Tags: xna, directx, monogame

I am developing a side scroller game using monogame 3.0 (XNA-C#). I am using a TriangleStrip to draw the ground and a spritebatch to draw a fence. I want the fence to be on top of the ground but it seems to be using a different axis (negative instead of positive). In order to align things up I need to flip the fence and use a negative x and y. Both the sprite and the primitive are using the same view  matrix and project.

Why is the spritebatch need a negative axis while the primitive is using a positive one when they are using the same matrixes?

```cs
protected override void Initialize()
{
    viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Vector3.Zero, new Vector3(0,1, 0));
    projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0,GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,  
                        0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0f, 200f) *Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(.5f, .5f, 1f));

    GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState.CullMode = CullMode.None;


    _groundBasicEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);
    _groundBasicEffect.View = viewMatrix;
    _groundBasicEffect.Projection = projectionMatrix;
    _groundBasicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
    _groundBasicEffect.World = world;

    _fenceBasicEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);
    _fenceBasicEffect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Vector3.Zero, new Vector3(0,1,  0));
    _fenceBasicEffect.Projection = projectionMatrix;
    _fenceBasicEffect.TextureEnabled = true;
    _fenceBasicEffect.World = world;     

    base.Initialize();
}
protected override void LoadContent()
{
        _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        fenceTexture = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Fence1");
        vertexData = new VertexPositionColor[8];
        vertexData[0] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Color.Black);
        vertexData[1] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 400, 0), Color.Black);
        vertexData[2] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(200, 0, 0), Color.Black);
        vertexData[3] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(200, 400, 0), Color.Black);
        vertexData[4] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(300, 0, 0), Color.Black);
        vertexData[5] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(300, 430, 0), Color.Black);
        vertexData[6] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1200, 0, 0), Color.Black);
        vertexData[7] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(1200, 430, 0), Color.Black);
        vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), vertexData.Length, BufferUsage.None);
        vertexBuffer.SetData(vertexData);

    }
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
        GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);

        _groundBasicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
        GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, vertexData, 0, vertexData.Length -2);

        _spriteBatch.Begin(0, null, null, null, null, _fenceBasicEffect);
        _spriteBatch.Draw(fenceTexture, Vector2.Zero, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1130, 221), Color.White, 0, new Vector2(0, 200), 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        _spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

**How it looks...**
[image: How it looks]

**How I expect it to look...**
[image: How I expect it to look]

In order to get this look I need to change the Draw of the fence to this...

```
_spriteBatch.Draw(fenceTexture, Vector2.Zero, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1130, 221), Color.White, 0, new Vector2(0, -400), 1, SpriteEffects.FlipVertically, 0);
```

Comment: Niko, the question is why is the spritebatch need a negative axis while the primitive is using a positive one when they are using the same matrixes?

Comment: If this works correctly in XNA but not on MonoGame, then please log an issue on github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues.